# ASP.NET CORE2.1: Host on Ubuntu18.04/Apache2: Proxy not working

Tags: apache, asp.net-core, ubuntu

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I followed the above tutorial and configured my Ubuntu 10.08 machine to run Apache server. I also configured the machine to run Asp.NET Core 2.1 web api (MyApp.dll) and it runs fine(I am able to access it on http://localhost:5000/api/Card).
I configured my Apache server as follows for proxy:

sudo vi /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/myapp-netcore.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
   ServerName www.myubuntuvm.com  
   ProxyPreserveHost On  
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/  
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/  
   
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/netcore-error.log  
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/netcore-access.log common  
</VirtualHost>
```

Web Api's Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

When I try to access the machine's ip(on port 80) in a browser, I am able to see the Apache home page(Apache is installed and working fine). As per the above config, if I try to go to
http://<machine_ip>/api/Card, I get the error "THe requested URL was not found on this server."
Is my configuration correct? How do I fix this error?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: I also followed the site https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-net-core-application-on-linux/ to configure my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the site working by following the below steps:

1. In my Startup.cs, I commented out the line

   app.UseHttpsRedirection();
   Edit: This did not have any effect on me resolving my issue. So, keep it.
2. In my APache2 /etc/apache2.ports.conf, I added the line

   Listen 8080
3. In my /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/myapp-netcore.conf file, I modified the VirtualHosts configuration as follows(this configuration makes sure that requests coming in on port 8080 are redirected to localhost:5000 where my ASP.NET Core app is running):

   ```
    <VirtualHost *:8080>  
       ServerName www.myubuntuvm.com  
       ProxyPreserveHost On  
       ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/  
       ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/  

       ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/netcore-error.log  
       CustomLog /var/log/apache2/netcore-access.log common  
    </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Open up ports on Ubuntu server for ports 80, 5000, 8080

   sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
   sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp
   sudo ufw allow 5000/tcp